# I would like to find the nearest larger papersize from a list

Tags: c#, linq

I would like to find the nearest equal or larger papersize from the list shown in the code.

```
List<PaperSize> paper = new List<PaperSize>();

paper.Add(new PaperSize("B5", 516, 729));
paper.Add(new PaperSize("A5", 420, 595));
paper.Add(new PaperSize("A4", 595, 842));
paper.Add(new PaperSize("B4", 729, 1032));
paper.Add(new PaperSize("A4L", 842, 595));
paper.Add(new PaperSize("A3", 1191, 842));
paper.Add(new PaperSize("A2", 1685, 1190));
paper.Add(new PaperSize("A1", 2384, 1685));
paper.Add(new PaperSize("A0", 3371, 2384));

int width = 1189;
int height = 840;

string name = paper.SkipWhile(p => p.PaperWidth < width && p.PaperHeight < 
    height).First().PaperName;

Console.WriteLine("Nearest equal or larger papersize is " + name);
```

If I provide the width 1189 and the height 840 I expect paper A3 is selected, but the result is A4.
How can I return A3?

EDIT: Indeed the list is not always ordered in a specific way. Because of that @Johnny and the suggestions of @Knoop solved my issue. Next to that I forgot to include my PaperSize with its properties PaperName, PaperWidth and PaperHeight, but you all assumed correctly that I had this.

Comment: keep in mind in the current solution a guess was made towards what you might consider "nearest papersize". Since this seems to be for printing it might be more beneficial to OrderBy total unused pixels (slightly more complicated then the proposed OrderBy). This could in practice reduce the amount of wasted paper, which I assume is part of the goal (safe the trees!!)

Comment: nvm, just noticed the area addition was already mentioned in another answer:-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, the `paper` list should not be sorted in advance:

```
paper.Where(p => p.PaperWidth  - width >= 0 && p.PaperHeight  - height >= 0)
    .OrderBy(p => p.PaperWidth - width + p.PaperHeight  - height)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: The question is for equality or greater, this takes strictly the greater papers. So `p => p.W >= width` would be the way to go. Also probably better to take the `FirstOrDefault()` instead of `First()`. Apart from that this answer is probably what OP is looking for.

Answer (score 6):

Change your `&&` to `||`. You want to skip while either the width *or* height is too small.

```
string name = paper.SkipWhile(p => p.PaperWidth < width || p.PaperHeight < 
    height).First().PaperName;
```

Of course, another perhaps clearer way of writing this is simply:

```
string name = paper
    .First(p => p.PaperWidth >= width && p.PaperHeight >= height)
    .PaperName;
```

It's also worth taking account of the fact that there may not be a paper size large enough. This sets `name` to null if that's the case.

```
string name = paper
    .FirstOrDefault(p => p.PaperWidth >= width && p.PaperHeight >= height)
    ?.PaperName;
```

Of course, these only work if your list of paper sizes is strictly ordered by area, with the smallest first. If this isn't the case, you can choose the paper size with the smallest wasted space:

```
int area = width * height;

string name = paper
    .Where(p => p.PaperWidth >= width && p.PaperHeight >= height)
    .OrderBy(p => p.PaperWidth * p.PaperHeight - area)
    .FirstOrDefault()
    ?.PaperName;
```

Comment: FirstOrDefault?

Comment: I just copied his code - I didn't want to introduce edits which didn't directly relate to solving his question.

Comment: He doesn't have `?.PaperName` or `FirstOrDefault` in his code.

Comment: Indeed, and his list is ordered by size. I assume he's thought of that. Wait, actually that's not entirely true. I'll add a note.

Comment: @croxy but he should have a `FirstOrDefault` to avoid a `NullreferenceException`

Answer (score 0):

> Requirement:
>   Given a width and height give me the Name of the smallest PaperSize that is larger than this width and height

There is something tricky about this.

Suppose you have width and height of 100 and 100. You have two papers:

- PaperSize A has width 105 and height 2000,
- PaperSize B has with width 110 and height 110.

Both papers are large enough. If you first look at width, you'd take Paper A, because it has the smallest Width. However Paper B seems way smaller than Paper A.

So first you'll have to think by yourself: **when is a Paper smaller than another Paper?**. You'll need a PaperComparer class that implements `IComparer<PaperSize>`:

```
class PaperSizeComparer : Comparer<PaperSize>
{
    public static IComparer AreaComparer {get;} = new PaperSizeComparer();

    public override int Compare(PaperSize x, PaperSize y)
    {
        ... TODO: implement your definition of smaller PaperSize
    }
}
```

Now it is up to you to define when you consider one PaperSize to be smaller than another PaperSize. You could go for Width and then for Height. Personally I'd go for Area Size:

```
private static readonly IComparer<int> areaComparer = Comparer<int>.Default;

public int CalcArea(PaperSize x)
{
    return x.Width * x.Height;
}

public override int Compare(PaperSize x, PaperSize y)
{
    // null PaperSizes are smallest
    if (x == null)
    {
        if (y == null)
           // both null: equal
           return 0;
        else
           // x null, y not null: x is smaller
           return -1;
    }
    else if (y == null) return +1; // x not null; y null: larger
    else
    {   // x and y both not null: compare areas:
        int areaX = this.CalcArea(x);
        int areaY = this.CalcArea(y);
        return areaComparer.Compare(areaX, areaY);
    }
}
```

Now that you've defined your comparer, your LINQ is easy:

```
IEnumerable<PaperSize> availablePaperSizes = ...
int width = ...
int height = ...
```

> Give me the Name of the smallest paper that is larger than this width and height

```
var smallestFittingPapersizeName = availablePaperSizes
    .Where(paperSize => paperSize.Width >= width && paperSize.Height >= height)
    .OrderBy(paperSize, PaperSizeComparer.AreaComparer)
    .Select(paperSize => paperSize.Name)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

> When concatening LINQ statements, always make sure that only the last statement is the one that does not return IEnumerable!

Notes:

- This LINQ statement always works, even on empty, or non-sorted collections of availablePaperSizes
- if in future you decide you want to define "smaller papersize" differently, the LINQ statement does not have to change

### Optimization

It is quite a waste to order all papersizes if you only want the smallest one. Consider using [Enumerable.Aggregate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate?view=netframework-4.7.2) to get the smallest `PaperSize`

```
    // instead of OrderBy:
    .Aggregate( (paperSizeX, paperSizeY) =>
       ((PaperSizeComparer.AreaComparer.Compare(paperSizeX, paperSizeY) <= 0) ??
          // paperSizeX smaller or equal; X remains the smallest
          paperSizeX :
          // paperSizeX larger: Y is the new smalles:
          paperSizeY)
```

Alas, this won't work on an empty collection. Besides it looks quite misty.

Consider writing an extension function that returns the smallest or default on any sequence:

```
public TSource MinOrDefault<TSource> (this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    IComparer<TSource) comparer)
{
    // TODO: exception if source == null
    if (comparer == null)
       comparer = Comparer<TSource>.Default; // use default comparer

    var enumerator = source.GetEnumerator();
    if (enumerator.MoveNext())
    {   // we have at least one source element:
        var smallest = enumerator.Current;

        // continue with the rest of the input sequence:
        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            // there is still another item
            if (comparer.CompareTo(smallest, enumerator.Current) > 0)
            {
                 // found a smaller item:
                 smallest = enumerator.Current;
            }
         }
         return smallest;
    }
    else
    {   // input collection empty; return default
        return default(TSource);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
PaperSize smallestFittingPaperSize = availablePaperSizes
    .Where(paperSize => paperSize.Width >= width && paperSize.Height >= height)
    .Min(PaperSizeComparer.AreaCompaerer);
```